# How do I access DWM's "desktop" surface in the recommended manner?

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop, gdi, dwm

Classic GDI way to access - `GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP)`/`GetWindowDC(HWND_DESKTOP)` - has been [discouraged by Greg Schechter of Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2006/05/02/588934.aspx) due off-screen rendering and blitting directly into framebuffer caused by DWM. Also, [Platform SDK reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa969536#BLURPRACTICES) recommends to avoid write access.
However, neither of cited sources provide an alternative recommendation.

So, what I should use instead of classic GDI method to be DWM-friendly?

Comment: Create a window and draw into the window.

Comment: @Raymond Chen of Microsoft, that works around write access deprecation. But what about read access Greg advises against?

Comment: Reads are slow no matter how you slice it. But why are you reading from the screen at all? Don't mess with somebody else's pixels.

Comment: @Raymond Chen, for example, screen capture purposes.

Comment: If it's infrequent, then you may as well just do the fullscreen BitBlt. If you are doing video recording, use [desktop duplication](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=356).